# Using CUDA Shared Memory to Improve Global Access Patterns

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I have the following kernel to get the magnitude of a bunch of vectors:

```
__global__ void norm_v1(double *in, double *out, int n)
{
    const uint i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < n)
    {
        double x = in[3*i], y = in[3*i+1], z = in[3*i+2];
        out[i] = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
}
```

However due to the packing of `in` as `[x0,y0,z0,...,xn,yn,zn]` it performs poorly with the profiler indicating a 32% global load efficiency.  Repacking the data as `[x0, x1, ..., xn, y0, y1, ..., yn, z0, z1, ..., zn]` improves things greatly (with the offsets for `x`, `y`, and `z` changing accordingly).  Runtime is down and efficiency is up to 100%.

However, this packing is simply not practical for my application.  I therefore wish to investigate the use of shared memory.  My idea is for each thread in a block to copy three values (`blockDim.x` apart) from global memory -- yielding coalesced access.  Under the assumption of a maximum `blockDim.x = 256` I came up with:

```
#define BLOCKDIM 256

__global__ void norm_v2(double *in, double *out, int n)
{
    __shared__ double invec[3*BLOCKDIM];

    const uint i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    invec[0*BLOCKDIM + threadIdx.x] = in[0*BLOCKDIM+i];
    invec[1*BLOCKDIM + threadIdx.x] = in[1*BLOCKDIM+i];
    invec[2*BLOCKDIM + threadIdx.x] = in[2*BLOCKDIM+i];
    __syncthreads();

    if (i < n)
    {
        double x = invec[3*threadIdx.x];
        double y = invec[3*threadIdx.x+1];
        double z = invec[3*threadIdx.x+2];

        out[i] = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
}
```

However this is clearly deficient when `n % blockDim.x != 0`, requires knowing the maximum `blockDim` in advance and generates incorrect results for `out[i > 255]` when tested with an `n = 1024`.  How should I best remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can solve the `out[i > 255]` problem:

```
__shared__ double shIn[3*BLOCKDIM];

const uint blockStart = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

invec[0*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x] = in[ blockStart*3 + 0*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x];
invec[1*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x] = in[ blockStart*3 + 1*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x];
invec[2*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x] = in[ blockStart*3 + 2*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x];
__syncthreads();

double x = shIn[3*threadIdx.x];
double y = shIn[3*threadIdx.x+1];
double z = shIn[3*threadIdx.x+2];

out[blockStart+threadIdx.x] = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
```

As for `n % blockDim.x != 0` I would suggest padding the input/output arrays with 0 to match the requirement.

If you dislike the `BLOCKDIM` macro - explore using `extern __shared__ shArr[]` and then passing 3rd parameter to kernel configuration:

```
norm_v2<<<gridSize,blockSize,dynShMem>>>(...)
```

the `dynShMem` is the dynamic shared memory usage (in bytes). This is extra shared memory pool with its size specified at run-time, where all `extern __shared__` variables will be initially assigned to.

---

What GPU are you using? Fermi or Kepler *might* help your original code with their L1 caching.

---

If you don't want to pad your `in` array, or you end up doing similar trick somewhere else, you may want to consider implementing a device-side `memcopy`, something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void memCopy(T* destination, T* source, size_t numElements) {
    //assuming sizeof(T) is a multiple of sizeof(int)
    //assuming one-dimentional kernel (only threadIdx.x and blockDim.x matters) 
    size_t totalSize = numElements*sizeof(T)/sizeof(int);
    int* intDest = (int*)destination;
    int* intSrc = (int*)source;
    for (size_t i = threadIdx.x; i < totalSize; i += blockDim.x) {
        intDest[i] = intSrc[i];
    }
    __syncthreads();
}
```

It basically treats any array as an array of `int`-s and copy the data from one location to another. You may want to replace the underlying `int` type with `double`-s or `long long int` if you work with 64-bit types only.

Then you can replace the copying lines with:

```
memCopy(invec, in+blockStart*3, min(blockDim.x, n-blockStart));
```